# How to get current location in a TextView?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an activity when I click on a button it has to return a google map and while confirmation the fragment disappears and it shows a TextView in my activity containing the current address.  I saw similar questions but they don't solve that particular issue.

Comment: You don't need google maps to fetch user location. You need to use location manager class

Comment: post your code @Maryam

Comment: I haven't written a code yet for searching , i have created an activity containing a button and when I click on it it returns  another activity , no special code

Comment: you mean "current address" like "street A building B"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Comment: @VadimEksler yes that what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to make to steps:
1) get location latlng via FusedLocationProviderClient like `mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener()`
Or `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(...)`

After getting `Location location`:

2) [Accessing adress,states from longitude amd lattitude with google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695524/accessing-adress-states-from-longitude-amd-lattitude-with-google-api)